# Click handler on table using Knockout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout-2.0

C#/MVC/Knockout

I'm playing around with knockout and I can't seem to get a click handler to work on the name column.  However, I can add in an image and assign a click handler to it.  It seems to be an issue if the column is being assigned a databind.

This is an example:

```
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: CurrentFeeds" class="table-news-body">
                        <tr class="panel-danger">
                            <td id="AllFeeds" data-bind="text: RSSName, click: $parent.showfeed" class="h3"></td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.showFeed"class="btn btn-white btn-sm">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            @if (bIsEditor)
                            {
                                <td>
                                    <button data-bind='click: $.deleteFeed' class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        Remove
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            }
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

If I change the allfeeds line to this:

```
<td id="AllFeeds" data-bind="text: RSSName, click: $parent.showfeed" class="h3"></td>
```

I don't get an error message but I can't click on that column.

However, if I add in this code:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.showFeed"class="btn btn-white btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
</td>
```

I can click on the icon that's created for it.

Whats going on?

Comment: Is the trailing `<td>` in your example the beginning of another `<td>` or should it actually be a `</tr>`?

Comment: There's something else going on somewhere - doing it on the `<td>` [should work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/9q8o3Ldv/2/).

Comment: I just updated the code to include the whole block.  The tags do match...

Comment: I just noticed you have `showfeed` on the `<td>` and `showFeed` (capital F) on the `<a>` - is that the issue or just a typo in your example here?

Comment: James; you nailed it. Thanks!  I'm so used to VS auto correcting/selecting variables and/or telling me that something's not right.  I wish it would do that in mvc coding as well. Many thanks!

Comment: Ok cool (FWIW have voted to close this Q as offtopic->typo).  I'm now wondering why this doesn't show up as an error in the browser dev console due to the function not existing... time to investigate and possibly raise a knockout issue...